# How to submit selected checkbox items?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, struts2

I have a list of items that need to be selected and take an action based on user's request.
User selects the items and click on one of the btns to do something on the items.

My code is as following but I am not sure how to complete it. I believe, need to put them in a form to be submitted or pass the but not sure how to have a form with two submit btns, (if I need to have ).

```
 <body>
        <p><b>Shopping cart</b></p>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <c:forEach items="${mycart.items}" var="item">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="Items" 
                                                         value="${item.ID}"/>  
                        </td>
                        <td>
                           Name : ${item.name}

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <a href="checkout" onclick="checkout()">checkout</a>
        <a href="delete" onclick="delete()">Delete</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can easily have two `<input type="submit" name="something" />` in one `<form>`
if you want to differentiate the actions, just use different `name` for each submit button

EDIT:

```
<form ...>
   ...
   ...
   <input id="b1" type="submit" name="edit" value="Edit"/>
   <input id="b2" type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete"/>
</form>
```

If the form above is submitted by clicking #b1, then your request will contain a parameter named "edit". If the submit is triggered by #b2, then it will contain "delete".

Comment: then how to recognize which one is clicked in action?

Answer (score 0):

I think following script might let you obtain what items are checked.
With jQuery, you need implement your checkout() like this

```
function checkout() {
    $('input[name="Items"]:checkbox').each(function() {
        if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
            alert($(this).val() + 'is checked');
        } else {
            alert($(this).val() + 'is not checked');
        }
    }
    );     

}
```